# Symfony2, acess/use the custom class in another custom class

Tags: php, symfony

How to load/access a custom class in the custom class in Symfony 2 not using service container?

If i try to use the custom logger as shown below i am getting the error:

`Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter::__construct() must implement interface Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface, none given, called in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym\just2\src\MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\EventDiff.php on line 23 and defined`

Stack Trace:

```
in src\MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter.php at line 12  -
private $logger;
public function __construct( LoggerInterface $logger ) // here they show the error
{
    $this->logger = $logger;
}
```

src\MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter.php

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\Components;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;

class LogWriter
{

    private $logger;

    public function __construct( LoggerInterface $logger )
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function log($msg)
    {
        $this->logger->log($msg);
    }
}
```

src\MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\Diff.php

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff;

//use MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter;

class Diff 
{
    private $diffCluesArr; 
    private $name; 
    private $logWriter;

    public function __construct ($logger) {
        $this->name= ""; 
        $this->diffCluesArr = [];
        $this->logWriter = $logger; 
        //$this->logWriter = new $logWriter; //changed here 
    } 

    public function array_diff_str_o ( $arr1, $arr2, $str ) {
        $this->logWriter("<br> In Diff  function array_diff_str_o ");
   //...
```

src\MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\EventDiff.php

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff;

use MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\Diff;
use MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter;

/**
 * Event normalizer
 */
class EventDiff extends Diff
{
    private $diffCluesArr; 
    private $name; 
    private $logw;

    // does not work
   // public function __construct (LogWriter $logger) {
   //     $this->logw= $logger;
  //      parent::__construct($this->logw);

    public function __construct () {
        $this->logw = new LogWriter();
        parent::__construct($this->logw);    
        $this->logw("<br> In constructor of EventDiff");
        $this->name= "event"; 
        $this->diffCluesArr = array( 
                //1 means compare normally
                //2 means compare the values of the keys
                'id' => 1,
// ..
```

app\config\services.yml

```
services:
    meeting.logw:
        class:     MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter
        arguments: ["@logger"]

    meeting.diff.diff:
        class:     'MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\Diff' 
        arguments: ["@meeting.logw"]

    meeting.diff.event:
        class: 'MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\EventDiff'
        parent: meeting.logw
        #the same error: parent: meeting.diff.diff
```

src\MeetingBundle\Controller\EventMapController.php

```
//.. 
    $diffentiator = $this->get('meeting.diff.event');
    $diffentiator->array_diff_str_o( $arrEventOld, $arrEventNew, $msg );
//..
```

---

//**** THE OLD VERSION OF THE QUESTION

If i try to use the custom logger as shown below i am getting the error:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\Diff::__construct() must be an instance of MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\LoggerInterface, none given, called in C:\Bitnami\wampstack-5.6.20-0\apache2\htdocs\sym\just2\src\MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\EventDiff.php on line 16 and defined

Where is the mistake? The code is as follow:

`just2\src\MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter.php`

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\Components;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Log\LoggerInterface;

class LogWriter
{

    private $logger;

    public function __construct(LoggerInterface $logger) // the place of error
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function log($msg)
    {
        $this->logger->log($msg);
    }
}
```

`just2\src\MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\Diff.php`

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff;

use MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter;

class Diff 
{
    private $logWriter;

    public function __construct (LoggerInterface $logger) {
      //  the first mistake
        $this->logWriter = $logger;
    }

    public function array_diff_str_o ( $arr1, $arr2, $str ) {
        $this->logWriter("<br> In Diff  function array_diff_str_o "); 
    //.. 
}
```

// src\MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\EventDiff.php

```
<?php

namespace MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff;

use MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\Diff;
/** Provides clue how to calculate the differences between entities instances */
class EventDiff extends Diff
{
   private $diffCluesArr; 
   private $name; 

    public function __construct () {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->logWriter("<br> In constructor of EventDiff");
        $this->name= "event"; 
        $this->diffCluesArr = array( 
                //1 means compare normally
                //2 means compare the values of the keys
                'id' => 1,
//...
```

just2\src\MeetingBundle\Controller\EventMapController.php

```
    /** * @Route("/edit/{id}", name="event_jsMap_edit")
     * @Method("GET|POST")
     * @Template("MeetingBundle:Event:ev_jsMap_edit.html.twig")
     */
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {
...
$diffentiator = $this->get('meeting.diff.event');
$diffentiator->array_diff_str_o( $arrEventOld, $arrEventNew, $msg ); 
...
```

I also made logwrite to be a service, but maybe it is not necessary and i do not want it to be a service. I would like to use it as a individual class not as a part of a service container:
app\config\services.yml

```
services:
    events.logger:
        class:     MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter
        arguments: ["@logger"]

    meeting.diff.event:
        class: 'MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\EventDiff'

    #class Diff is not a service. Class EventDiff extends from Diff.
```

Comment: How do you instantiate the `Diff` object?

Comment: Can you show how you define `EventDiff` as a service?

Comment: Class` EventDiff` is a service, which extends from class `Diff`. Class `Diff` has several methods which are common for all the entities which calculate the difference between two instances if the same type of entity, thus i extend each `EntityDiff.php` from this class. Additionally. class `Diff` has a logger to log message from its methods.

Comment: Seems the error is in logger and logWriter variables. Sometimes i am tired and mix the variables.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely in the way you instantiate `Diff` in `EventDiff` class as the error message suggests. `LogWriter` seems allright.

Do you define `EventDiff` as a service as well with correct dependencies?

Edit: In `EventDiff` you're calling `parent::__construct();` without any parameter. However the parent `Diff` class takes one parameter. You probably want to inject a service to `EventDiff` that'll be passed to its parent in the constructor.

Comment: I made the corrections to the question. It is defined as  `meeting.diff.event:
        class: 'MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\EventDiff' `.

Comment: Seems the error is in logger and logWriter variables. Sometimes i am tired and mix the variables.

Comment: I updated my answer, you're not calling the parent constructor correctly.

Comment: thank you. Is this possible without service injection?

Comment: @olga I don't think so :).

Comment: @olga To be precise, of course you can pass to the parent whatever you want but I assume you want to leave all dependency resolution on Symfony2 and not doing it yourself.

Comment: I updated the question. Now i am getting another error, about the LoggerInterface. Seems they want me to pass the logger interface somewhere.

Comment: Because `LogWriter` requires an instance with `LoggerInterface` as well that you don't provide in `EventDiff ` on the line `$this->logw = new LogWriter();`. Thus the error.

Comment: Thank you, i will reply in a week, busy now. I do not like dependecy injection, because it makes website slow as far as i understand. I am sorry, i will reply in week-two when i have time to check. Main task was to calcualte difference before/after entity update. I managed with differentiator calss without logger. It works. For logger i have to think more.

Answer (score 0):

You could [Manage Common Dependencies with Parent Services](http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html). Try defining the service defining the `parent` attribute in the following manner:

```
services:
    events.logger:
        class:     MeetingBundle\Components\LogWriter
        arguments: ["@logger"]

    meeting.diff.event:
        class: 'MeetingBundle\Components\Serializer\Diff\EventDiff'
        parent: events.logger
```

Hope this help